# Weird behaviour in model (Ruby on Rails 4)

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a weird behaviour in my model code, but I am not sure if this is my problem or is it some weird issue with Ruby on Rails.

I've an associated has_many :chat_user #linked to ChatUser

and I've defined

```
Class A

def guest 

 chat_user #returning chat_user from has_many

end

end
```

I've 2 records of ChatUser which is linked to this model class

When I called object of Chat A .chat_user -> count and each return 2 records.

When I called object of .guest -> count return 2, but each loop only once!

What could be the issue? I am using Rails 4.0.0 with Puma server.

Comment: weird, the moment i change my code back to use chat_user, iam getting only 1 record again...

Comment: IMO you should include cleaner code: it's not very understandable as it is right now. I was going to advise you to use a `belongs_to` association, but since your code it's not clear, I'm not sure if that's an option.

Comment: hi fer garcia, yes i do have belongs_to inside class ChatUser to link back to ChatA

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of hard to understand. One thing that's obviously wrong, though, is `has_many :chat_user`. That should say `has_many :chat_users`.

Comment: hi bratsche, still same issue

Comment: hi, ive another table clearing cache in a different connection of the same user as live stream, does it causes the database to behave strangely? eg: UserNotification.connection.clear_query_cache

Comment: very odd behaviour, when i tried to run the same code in rails console, the problem does not persists

Comment: found the issue, silly me, ive actually returned a custom where query with limit 1 applied to chat_user, hidden in a function.. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I've actually returned a custom where query with limit 1 applied to chat_user, hidden in a function.